# When subscribed to multiple channels, how do I know which channel a message came in on?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

According to the docs, you can subscribe to multiple channels like so:

```js
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel : ['my_channel_1','my_channel_2','my_channel_3'],
    message : function(message) {
        console.log(message) 
    }
});
```

I have my app subscribing to `TEST` and `LIVE`.  My question is, is there any way in the `message` event to determine what channel it came from without including it in the payload? (I confirmed `m` is the full object I sent and nothing more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **PubNub JSV3**, you can get the **channel name** of your message by using **message** callback.

Here is a sample code of **PubNub JSV3**:

```
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel : ['my_channel_1','my_channel_2','my_channel_3'],
    message : function( message, env, channel ){
        console.log(message);
        console.log(channel)
    },
    connect : function(){
        console.log("Connected")
    },
    disconnect : function(){
        console.log("Disconnected")
    },
    reconnect : function(){
        console.log("Reconnected")
    },
    error : function(){
        console.log("Network Error")
    }, 
})
```

In **PubNub JSV4**, you can get the **channel name** of your message by using **addListener** function. This function also provides many other options like status of your connection(e.g 'connected', 'disconnected' etc) in **PubNub JSV3** all of them are bundled inside subscribe.

Here is a sample code of **PubNub JSV4**:

```
pubnub.addListener({
    status: function(statusEvent) {
        if (statusEvent.category === "PNConnectedCategory") {
            var newState = {
                new: 'connected'
            };
            PubNub.setState(
                { 
                    state: newState 
                }, 
                function (status) {
                    console.log('connected', status)
                }
            );
        } else if (statusEvent.category === "PNUnknownCategory") {
            var newState = {
                new: 'error'
            };
            PubNub.setState(
                { 
                    state: newState 
                }, 
                function (status) {
                    console.log(statusEvent.errorData.message)
                }
            );
        } else if (statusEvent.category === "PNNetworkIssuesCategory") {
            var newState = {
                new: 'disconnected'
            };
            PubNub.setState(
                { 
                    state: newState 
                }, 
                function (status) {
                    console.log('disconnected', status)
                }
            );
        }
        else if (statusEvent.category === "PNReconnectedCategory") {
            var newState = {
                new: 'reconnect'
            };
            PubNub.setState(
                { 
                    state: newState 
                }, 
                function (status) {
                    console.log('reconnected', status)
                }
            );
        }
    },
    message: function(message) {
        console.log(message)
    },
    presence: function(presenceEvent) {
        console.log(presenceEvent)
    }
})

pubnub.subscribe({ 
    channels : ['my_channel_1','my_channel_2','my_channel_3']
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Listener Message Callback Parameter

The parameter that is passed into the `message` listener has the following structure:

> I edited/updated the `channel` and `subscription` key names below. The old key names were `actualChannel` and `subscribedChannel` but these are deprecated as of PubNub JavaScript SDK v4.0.9 because they were confusing.

```js
{
    "subscription": undefined, // as of SDK v4.0.10
    "channel": "ch1", // as of SDK v4.0.10
    "timetoken": "14721821326909151", // publish timetoken
    "message": {"data":"hello"} // the message
}

// example code to get the data above that is passed into 'message'
pubnub.addListener({
    message: function(m) {
        // handle message
        var channel = m.channel;
        var pubTT = m.timetoken;
        var msg = m.message;
    },
    presence: function(p) {
        // handle presence
    },
    status: function(s) {
        // handle status
    }
});
```

*NOTE: About `subscription` attribute*

- If the client is subscribed to the *channel group* and not directly to the *channel*, then the `subscription` attribute would hold the value of the channel group that the channel is in.

```js
        subscription: channelGroupFoo
        channel: channelBar
```

- If the client was subscribed via *wildcard* and not directly to the *channel*, then the `subscription` attribute would be the *wildcard pattern match* that the *channel* was part of.

```js
        subscription: foo.*
        channel: foo.bar
```

- But the `channel` attribute will always be the `channel` that the message was published to/received on.